# how to plot a function (partial derivative) in maple using 3D plot

Tags: graphics, maple

I have the following function

```
u := proc (x, t) options operator, arrow; 
    50+sum((100*n*Pi*sin(n*Pi)+100*cos(n*Pi)-100)*cos((1/10)*n*Pi*x)*exp(-(1/100)*n^2*Pi^2*t)/(n^2*Pi^2), n = 1 .. 20) 
    end proc;

plot3d(u(x, t), x = 0 .. 10, t = 0 .. 20)
```

I am trying to plot it in Maple, but is not giving me the right 3D shape.

Comment: What you mean by the right shape?

Comment: Derivative w.r.t what?

Comment: I corrected your code (missing multiplication operators and corrected `pi` to `Pi`). Is it still not working?

Answer (score 0):

```
restart:
u := proc (x, t) options operator, arrow; 
    50+sum((100*n*Pi*sin(n*Pi)+100*cos(n*Pi)-100)*cos((1/10)*n*Pi*x)*exp(-(1/100)*n^2*Pi^2*t)/(n^2*Pi^2), n = 1 .. 20) 
    end proc:

plot3d(u(x, t), x = 0 .. 10, t = 0 .. 20);
```

[image]

```
plot3d(diff(u(x, t),x), x = 0 .. 10, t = 0 .. 20);
```

[image]

Comment: `plot3d` is not part of the `plots` package so `with(plots):` is redundant here. @alqoshhazkeal has not replied to my comment on the question, but I am not convinced that the error persists after my edit, i.e. the problem was due to small errors in the code.

Comment: @Therkel What error? After you made the changes, I don't see any syntax error anymore. You are right about `plot3d`.

Comment: See [the first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42242344/1). That code does not run.

Comment: @Therkel That's What I am saying after you made the correction there is no syntax issue anymore

Comment: I suppose my point is that there is no difference between the question and your answer. :)

Comment: @Therkel The title says how to plot `partial diff`. BTW, you are not suppose to correct the syntax of the code by editing the question. It will not be helpful for the visitors.